# TYPE type_name IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(64) from Oracle in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, types

Is there an equivalent type declaration in PostgreSQL to this one in Oracle:

```
TYPE type_name IS TABLE OF OBJECT
```

I have a type:

```
CREATE TYPE t_pick AS
(
    bet_no  integer,
    result  smallint
);
```

And now I want to create table using this type. In Oracle I did this with a declaration like above. But how to do this in PostgreSQL?
Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define array types or collection types in PostgreSQL.
But you can create a composite type and then use it in an array:

```
CREATE TYPE t_pick AS
( 
  bet_no integer;
  result smallint;
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo ..

DECLARE 
  var t_pick[];
BEGIN
 ...
```